# Obter parte de uma string

Tags: lua

Estou a ir buscar uns dados de um ficheiro em formato ics. O problema é que o ficheiro pode alterar varias vezes. Tenho este código para por em cada variável cada dado de uma certa linha do ficheiro. Exemplo:

```
     for line in f:lines() do 
       f line:sub(1,5) == "RRULE" then --objet
            rule = line

            freq = string.match(rule,"FREQ=(.*);")
            until_ = string.match(rule,"UNTIL=(.*)")
            interval = string.match(rule,"INTERVAL=(.*)")
            count = string.match(rule,"COUNT=(.*)")
        end
      end
```

E isto são os vários exemplos da linha do ficheiro que posso obter:

```
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=10;COUNT=5

RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;INTERVAL=2

RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=19971224T000000Z
```

Como posso obter para por em cada variável diferente?

Comment: Qual é o problema?

Comment: Quero obter cada parametro da linha RRULE em cada variavel. Por exemplo obter o "DAILY" na variavel freq. O meu problema é que nem sempre todos acabam com um ;

Comment: Quais são os vários separadores existentes no teu ficheiro?

Comment: Os separadores da linha são o ponto e virgula. Mas utilizando os varios exemplos das linhas RRULE, o meu codigo nao funciona correctamente.

Comment: Você pode por um exemplo que possa ser executado mostrando exatamente como funciona e o que está dando errado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema com o seu código é o uso de `.*`, que é um padrão guloso, isto é, pega *tudo* a partir desse ponto.

Aqui está um modo robusto de pegar todos os campos de uma linha, qualquer que seja a ordem na qual eles aparecem:

```
for line in f:lines() do 
    if line:sub(1,5) == "RRULE" then
        local t={}
        line=line..";"
        for k,v in line:gmatch("(%w-)=(.-);") do
            t[k]=v
        end
        -- check that we have parsed the line correctly
        print(line)
        for k,v in pairs(t) do
            print(k,v)
        end
    end
end
```